# Gephi 0.9 multigraph and timestamp for narrative analysis

Tags: timestamp, gephi

I have been working on a narrative network analysis designed to illustrate relationship strategies employed within the Bible's book of Ruth. (Preliminary studies available on my site at www.edminsters.com/blog). Upon importing into gephi 0.8 the edge list would be compressed with multiple edges added up to a summed weight. The edge list looks something like this:

```
Source     Target     Interaction     Reference     Timestamp
Naomi      Ruth       Speech          1:8-9         1202
Naomi      Ruth       Speech          2:2           2103
Reepers    Boaz       Narrative       2:03          2202
```

Using the multigraph and timestamp functionality in v0.9 I hope to import the same edge list allowing for duplicate edges (colored by interaction) that can then be given duration in the narrative according to their timestamp.

Based on generated graphs in Gephi I have changed column names in my csv file from "Interaction" to "Kind" (for multigraph support) and "Timestamp" to a variety of names. But my list is still being reduced as it was before.

What do I need to do to preserve the original edge list on import and import my timestamps as such in gephi?

Comment: I just checked your data. It seems that Gephi 0.9 doesn't allow for multigraphs, same as 0.8.2. You will have to work with something else, perhaps Cytoscape